# Hugo: adding more pages to single-page themes

Tags: themes, singlepage, hugo

[Hugo](https://gohugo.io/overview/introduction/) is a general purpose website framework and a static site generator. However, most of [the themes](http://themes.gohugo.io/) are single page themes.

Is it possible to add more pages to these single-page themes in Hugo?

I am specifically interested in the [Dimension](http://themes.gohugo.io/dimension/) theme.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 4):

This depends on how the theme is constructed. In Dimension's case, the answer is no - you can add new markdown files to your content folder, but they will only be rendered on the index page, not as their own individual pages. If you want to generate multiple pages, you will have to either edit the theme or choose a new theme that supports multiple pages.

To edit the theme, see the docs on [customising a theme](https://gohugo.io/themes/customizing/) and [creating a theme](https://gohugo.io/themes/creation/). You will also need to know Hugo templates, so the [go template primer](https://gohugo.io/templates/go-templates/) is an essential read. Editing themes can be a little tricky, but if you have worked with other templating languages then it is not too much different.

In your case, you will want to edit `layouts/_default/single.html` to create a [single-page view](https://gohugo.io/templates/content/) for all of your markdown files. You will also need to edit `layouts/index.html` to link to them from the [index page](https://gohugo.io/templates/homepage/), otherwise no-one will find them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it easy to edit this theme?is there any instructions on how?

Comment: Thanks Jack, I upvoted your answer. Have you done this before? As I am very new to this it looks too complicated for me. If you have done this before and can send me a sample code, or if you can help me to do it, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

*Hugo is not just a general purpose website framework/generator. I have been using it for article publishing, news website and to generate a blog! Most of the themes are single pages because people created themes in the way they love. Although still in development, you can check my website Desktop Luxury that is fully static and built with hugo. It's super fast, **supports AMP** and users just love it. They can't tell the difference between Wordpress sites and Desktopluxury.com in terms of look. Note: The difference is clearly visible in terms of load time, speed and customization ability!*

Although it varies by theme, you can easily create a .md (file that contains content - similar to .html*) file out of your blog folder. For example, you want to create an About page. In the root folder that contains your hugo files, create a directory root/content/blog. Add permalinks to your config file that tells the theme to categorize files present in /root/content/blog folder as the blog files. Create the pages such as an about.md & contact.md in root/content folder. They won't show in the blog list, however, they'll be rendered and accessed by siteurl.xyz/about or siteurl.xyz/contact.

*I said .md file similar to .html file as the OP seems new to webdevelopment.

EDIT:

[Final homepage after adding few posts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wumm2.jpg)

I just downloaded the theme mentioned in the question, added few .md files by opening CMD in the root directory of Hugo website folder and running command ~~ $ hugo new professional.md ~~
Created various pages and added content in them just like we write articles. I achieved the result you wanted with no issue at all. It was super easy!

Comment: Inderdeep: thank you very much for the answer. Can you please make it complete by showing me how to add permalinks to my config file? If you can try your answer on the **Dimension** theme for Hugo (the link is in my question) and see if it works that would be great.

Comment: @TJ1, I have edited my answer. Hope that'd be clear. Do not hesitate to ask for a further demonstration, if needed.

Comment: Thanks, @rene for the information. Although I mentioned my website just for reference, I have removed the link.

Comment: how can I "Add permalinks to your config file that tells the theme to categorize files present in /root/content/blog folder as the blog files." Can you please show me exactly how by publishing the content of config file?

Comment: Looking at the link you provided all the pages you added are showing at the bottom of the main page if I have 40 pages this make it crowded and not practical. I don't want them to be shown

Comment: @Tj1, if you do not want those pages to show, then you'd have to create a blog like website. In that case, few pages (of your choice or the most recent posts) will show at the homepage while there'll be a 'Blog' or 'Posts' button where all other pages, in your case 40 pages will show up. Is it something you want to achieve? Because your theme is a single page theme that needs some minimal modification to work like that.

However, you can show those 40 pages somewhere else - such as a well categorized (and collapseable) navbar.

Comment: I want 40 separate pages, that are not shown in the main page. I want to be able to click on links to go from one page to the other. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @TJ1 Yes, it is possible (and quite easy to do so) by coding in such a way that all your .md files are rendered as blog posts. This way, you can link few specific pages to the homepage. However, it won't be a single page theme/site anymore!